# makes child widget transparent to it's parent background

Tags: dart, flutter

i try to make camera preview using dark background with opacity and have card area in middle section which is has transparent background. It's look like showing Dialog in mobile device with dark background but the dialog have transparent background through dark background.

i already acomplished using column and row widget such as :

```
Column(
  children : <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.Black54
      )
    ),

    Row(
      children : <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.Black54
          )
        ),

        CardWidget(
          width: cardWidth,
          height: cardHeight,
          Color: Colors.Transparent
        ),

        Expanded(
          child: Container(
             color: Colors.Black54
          )
        ),
      ]
    ),

    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.Black54
      )
    ),

  ]
)
```

But i wonder is there a simple way such as :

```
 Container(
  color: Colors.Black54,
  child: center(
    child: CardWidget(
      width: cardWidth,
      height: cardHeight,
      background: Colors.Transparent
    )
  )
)
```

Please let me know if there is another way to make it simple like code above. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this ?

[image]

If yes, here is the code :

```
new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            top: BorderSide(width: 300, color: Colors.grey[700]),
            left: BorderSide(width: 100, color: Colors.grey[700]),
            right: BorderSide(width: 100, color: Colors.grey[700]),
            bottom: BorderSide(width: 300, color: Colors.grey[700]),
          ),
          color: Colors.transparent),
    )
```

Comment: You can also add a widget as Container's child for you camera preview, it will be placed in the white rectangle

Comment: yes exactly like that. i wonder, is it shall fit with many variation of devices ?.
But thanks nice idea

Comment: You can change sizes by this : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2 (idem for height) to fit with all devices sizes

Comment: i made some calculation for card size. it shall guide the rest

Comment: How to remove this lines?